# Hapijs onPreResponse, forwarded response

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

For my api I need to have an md5 result for all routes, so I use:

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', function(request, reply) {
    var content = request.response.source;
    var code = request.response.statusCode;

    if(typeof request.headers.md5 != 'undefined' && code == 200) {
        content = md5(content);
    }

    if(!DEBUG && code != 200){
        content = "Error";
    }
    reply(content).code(code);
});
```

When the response is a 404 error, the `request.response` doesn't have a `response.statusCode`...
I can handle this with:

```
if(typeof code == 'undefined'){
    code = 404;
}
```

But when I try to view the documentation generated with Lout, I have this: 
[image: some html code]

How can I properly forward the code message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `reply.continue()` rather than `reply().code()`

A very similar question was answered here: https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/103